# Check if a key belongs to dictionary, avoid to store it again and increase the counter

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a table from a data set that should give me the words in the data set and the number of times they are repeated.

So for example:

**dataset** : `{ moon, moon, moon, sun }`

**table** (final result):

```
('moon') ==> 3
('sun') ==> 1
```

I thought to use a dictionary and play with the keys, so if during the iteration a word that is already a key is found, don't add it to the dictionary (that should represent the table) but increase the numeric value.

```
word_table = {}

for word in document.split():
    if word in word_table:
        word_table[word, somevalue] += 1
    else:
        word_table[word, somevalue] = 1
```

The `somevalue` is a secondary key that I am storing together with the word. This value can be **yes** or **no**. I am mentioning this because I am not sure if this can cause the problem (or better, the selection of the specific key I want to compare).

When I print the whole dictionary, I get a long list of words as keys (the program does not detect repetition) and all 1 in the counters.

---

**Output:**

```
('moon', 'yes') ==> 1
('moon', 'yes') ==> 1
('moon', 'yes') ==> 1
.........
```

Is there any other approach or data structure that should I use for this particular case? Or it is just the code?

Comment: An entry for `word, somevalue` is not an entry for `word`. `word in word_table` is checking for an entry for `word`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine for your dictionary key to be a tuple (though in your post it's unclear why you want to dot his). All you need to do is make sure that you're checking for that tuple in your `if` statement:

```
word_table = {}

for word in document.split():
    if (word,somevalue) in word_table:
        word_table[word, somevalue] += 1
    else:
        word_table[word, somevalue] = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is probably what you are looking for:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter("moon,moon,moon,sun".split(","))
Counter({'moon': 3, 'sun': 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the structure you need is the [counter](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/collection/python-collections-counter) structure from the **collections** package.  You simply feed it your list of words, and you get a dictionary structure filled with the words and counts.